# select web camera on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When you have multiple web cameras.

You can select web camera on the chrome , setting -> contents -> media

But,I would like to select camera from script.

How can I select camera by Html5 or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Introduction_to_the_Camera_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_the_Camera_API) It is huge code so I have not pasted it here.

This is camera API for DOM [Document Object Model]

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)
You'll have to use html5

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck. At the moment there doesn't seem to be a way in HMTL5 to list and select audio/video devices available.

Answer (score 0):

simply you cant select by script you can just turn on the default by getUsermedia api

Answer (score 0):

To select the webcam you need to have 2 steps.
1º step is about listing all devices:

```
<select id="video_id"></select>
<script>
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.msGetUserMedia);
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
          .then(function(devices) {
            devices.forEach(function(device) {
                if (device.kind == "videoinput"){
                    jQuery("#video_id").append("<option value='" + device.deviceId + "'>" + device.label + "</option>");
                }
              
            });
          });
</script>
```

Easy peasy. EnumerateDevices inside mediaDevices list all devices. I put each one using JQuery in the SELECT html. Now you have all options with all devices with the value being the ID of each device.

When someone select the device, it will trigger a function:

```
 jQuery("#video_id").change(function(){
     redo_video();
 })
```

Above jQuery sets the trigger when the select changes. It will fire the function redo_video()

```
 function redo_video(){
            
       constraints = {
             width: { ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
             height: {ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
             deviceId: { exact: jQuery("#video_id").val()  }
        }
        navigator.getMedia(
        {
           video: constraints,
           audio: false
        },
        function(stream) {               
            video = document.querySelector('#video');
            if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                video.mozSrcObject = stream;
              } else {
                try {
                  video.srcObject = stream;
                    console.log(stream);
                } catch (error) {
                     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
              }
                video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                   video.play();
             };
              
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log("An error occured! " + err);
        }
    );
            
}
```

The function restarts the video player choose a device with a specific deviceId (the option selected).