# Google Chrome 37: choose webcam/camera on android device

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, camera, media

Background: Google Chrome on Android. I have a webpage wich captures a picture using Javascript libraries.

I found everywhere and specifically [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603321/select-web-camera-on-google-chrome) that it's possible to change webcam by going to Settings > Content settings > Media.

Sadly I don't know from what version on that setting doesn't exist anymore, nowadays the *Content settings* just includes *cookies*, *javascript*, *poups*, *Google Translate*, *Location settings*, *Website settings*, so nothing related to which cam to use.

By default it uses the front camera, how can I switch to the rear one? thanks

Comment: maybe they dropped this settings because it can be choosen programmatically? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625007/enable-rear-camera-with-html5